# mod_rewrite url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I noticed on youtube their url does not have a file extension and querystring. I've been trying to emulate something similar but found I had to either include the file extension or a trailing slash.

```
members.php?agefrom=20&ageto=40&city=london (works)
members/?agefrom=20&ageto=40&city=london (works)
members?agefrom=20&ageto=40&city=london (doesnt work)
```

So I was just wondering how can I get the third case to work? i've tried a few things in the htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^members$ index.php?page=members&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
```

I have tried the above but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RewriteRule that you posted is correct for members.php? and for members?  It should not work with members/
You must have additional RewriteRules before this one that are getting applied first and are affecting this rule.

However, here is a rule that should still work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^members/?$ index.php?page=members&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
```

The /? is saying to match if the slash exists or if it doesn't exist.

Comment: i've given that a go and still no luck. Would I need to change anything in httpd.conf file perhaps?

Comment: Glad to hear you got the re-write working.  Since your other question is about Google & SEO and not about php or mod-rewrite I would recommend you post a separate question about that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the $ on the end?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^members/?$ index.php?page=members&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
```

This did work in the end, all I had to do was move it nearer the top of the htaccess file. I had the following line which I guess was being read instead.

```
....
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/members$ [OR]
....
```

I am changing my approach to SEO URL's because I was trying to find articles on how the googlebot actually crawls forms and how it prefers the GET method. I was using jquery to alter my action parameter to write the following URL:

```
/members/london/18-to-25
```

I dont know how much google likes jquery and whether it would scan javascript code. I am assuimg it just follows the HTML code and having done some research I have changed my form to use the GET method and so the bot can crawl my form without complaining so now my URL looks like this:

```
/members?location=london&agefrom=18&ageto=40
```

I am on the right track to assume this? or should I just stick with jquery to rewrite the action parameter for an seo friendly URL?